# using regex to escape folders in a 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've had a look at all kinds of online resources and can't quite work this out.

Would really appreciate a well explained answer so I can work this out and help others with it too!

I have this structure:
website.com/blog/year/month/day/blog-title/

and I need to create a 301 redirect removing the blog and date like so:
website.com/blog-title/

I've been trying all kinds of combinations of letters that I don't really understand without any luck.

Any pointers greatly appreciated,
Thanks!